# What could this REDIS StackExchange.Redis exception mean

Tags: exception, redis, stackexchange.redis

Am trying to understand what could the **REDIS** error mean. we have a master and a localhost as slave. from time to time we receive such an error which we think that it's produced from a call to big cache.but as i said it does not happen all the time

> Exception message: Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 2, mgr: ExecuteSelect, err: never, queue: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=32,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=32762,Min=32,Max=32767), clientName: BSKKAYSIS-IIS01

Comment: It's not a Redis but a StackExchange.Redis exception

Comment: yes you are right. and am looking for a meaning for it

Comment: This can be only answered by Marc Gravell

Comment: i hope he have some time to take a look @marc-gravell